# How to get a unique id with a simple custom gutenberg block in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying get a unique id for each custom gutenberg block. I'm found [useInstanceId](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/compose/src/hooks/use-instance-id). Is that possible to use with this syntax?

```js
registerBlockType('custom/block', {
    title: 'Custom',
    
    edit() {
        return (<p>{unqiue-block-id}</p>)
    },
    save() {
        return (<p>{unqiue-block-id}</p>)
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could solve this with the `clientId` out of `props`. Unfortunately it just lives in the props of the edit function. So you need to deliver the clientId as an extra attribute.
I myself was struggling too much getting this with `useInstanceId` done because you need to make it with a HigherComponent if I understand that right. So I went with the `clientId` solution.

I got the initial thought from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/329380/138448)

Here is what your code could look like to get it done with the `clientId`.

```
registerBlockType('custom/block', {
    title: 'Custom',

    attributes: {
        yourId: {
            type: 'string',
        }
    },

    edit: props => {
        const {
            attributes: {
                yourId,
            },
            clientId,
            setAttributes,
        } = props;

        setAttributes({ yourId: clientId });

        return (
            <p>{yourId}</p>
        );
    },

    save: props => {
        const {
            attributes: {
                yourId,
            },
        } = props;

        return (
            <p>{yourId}</p>
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you! Works great

Comment: Lars, me too but for now I'll go with this solution and have a look into the `useInstanceId` topic later. As far as I know you have to use a higher order component but that's a completely different topic.
If you'll find a good solution and example let us all know about it ;)

Comment: Also, if you're looking to use clientID as a CSS selector anywhere, then make sure to prepend it with a letter since sometimes clientId starts with a number, and that is not a valid CSS class name.  Like `let safeCssClientIdClass = 'a' + clientId`

Comment: Unfortunately, when the block or post is edited the `clientId` is updated and is unreliable to use as a CSS selector.